# Primeng icons not showing up on IE11 after creating prod build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, internet-explorer-11

I am creating an application with angular 6 and primeng. The problem I am facing is that primng icons such as calendar, dropdown arrow are visible when i run application with local build i.e ng serve but as soon as I create prod aot build the icons disappear on IE11.

I have tried making changes in polyfills file, have added 2 imports import 'es6-shim'and import 'web-animations-js' but have not got any success. IE security might be one of the reasons because as soon as I go to IE11 settings --> internet options--> security --> sites and uncheck "Include all local(intranet) sites not listed in other zones" check box then icons reappear on reloading.

I am not sure what to do will be great if anyone can provide solution.

Thanks.

Edit: Things are working fine in other browsers such as chrome and mozilla. 
In IE11 internet options-->security--> select local internet then click on sites and after unchecking "Include all local(intranet) sites not listed in other zones" the icons reappear after reloading.

Comment: How about other browsers, why not trying check/uncheck security options in IE 11 one by one? If you have more detailed information, you can ask a more detailed question. Please edit your question after trying this.

Comment: working fine in other browsers, have edited info related internet options of IE11

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get your resources from site-server-zones which are not listed in your intranet-zone. Ask your system-manager, and rearrange your working site-zones.

It is hard to advise when I do not know your network configuration, and I do not want to know it, but in there is the problem.

It would be easier, just to test your application in Chrome, there you have also a lot of developer supporting tools (for example Ctrl+Shift+I)

And when you want to test the rest of the world, do a test-deployment.